# python post request json

Tags: python, json, rest, post

I need to use Python to do a POST request using JSON format. What I have right now is

```
url = 'http://mysurl.org'
data = {my data }
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url,data= json.dumps(data, headers=headers)
```

The issue come when my data is not one line but 500 lines of :

```
[
{
    "Id" : "abc123",
    "usr": "u1",
    "pwd" : "p1"
},
{
    "Id" : "abc124",
    "usr": "u2",
    "pwd" : "p2"
},
{
    "Id" : "abc125",
    "usr": "u3",
    "pwd" : "p3"
}
.......
]
```

This really threw me off because "Id" field come from a random generater: `id = gennum()`
usr is from a query: `usr = sqlout[0][0]`, and pwd is from `pwd = sqlout[0][1]`.
I really do not have an idea how to read 500 line of data into my file `data=....`
I try to use `data.append` but do  not know how to continue after that.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[update] sorry that question is not specific. my data comes from three different area:
(1) id row come from an random number generator: gennum()
(2) from query my database. sqlout variable will have 500 lines of out put wiht : 
user, and pwd. so basically user = sqlout[0][0], and pwd will = sqlout[0][1] and they need to be in the post request body all together, in one request. so when I send the post request, my request bodywill contain 500 entries of json data like stated below. Hope this will clean the question up a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read content of the file using [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) and [`file.read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read):

```
with open('/path/to/json_file') as f:
    data = f.read()
url = 'http://mysurl.org'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

**UPDATE** after reading comments.

You can make dictionaries from multiple data sources using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
data = [{'id': id, 'usr': usr, 'pwd': pwd} for id,usr,pwd in 
        zip(id_data_generator, usr_data_generator, pwd_data_generator)]
```

Comment: You don't assign `data` anywhere. Did you mean `data=content`?

Comment: I appreciate the quick help, this definitely is helping. However, sorry  I did not make my question clear, i do not have a json file at this point, and how to ready the 3 different column of data(id, urs,and pwd) into my json file is really where I get stuck. again, I appreciate the quick reply.

Comment: @PChao, Where does the `data` in the question come from?

Comment: Oh Ok, data come from 3 different areas:

Comment: (1) id come from an id data generate

Comment: @PChao, Could you be more specific. **area** is too vague. Please update your question with that **areas**.

Comment: @PChao, Do you want something like this? `data = [{'id': id, 'usr': usr, 'pwd': pwd} for id,usr,pwd in zip(id_data_generator, usr_data_generator, pwd_data_generator)]`

Comment: Thanks so much! that is what I am looking for, falsetru. Thanks again.

Comment: @PChao, I updated the answer to include the last comment. If this helped you, you can tell the community so by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235).